# prevent damage to door from anxious dog

Tags: scratching

I got a new house and an anxious dog. When we leave, even for 10 min he paws at the door we leave out of and it's starting to get messed up and I need to protect it somehow.

I've tried all the calming crap and taken him to classes without any luck. He is an old dog that I adopted from a pound when he was 7 and he just has anxiety. When we leave even though he is now almost 13 he still doesn't think we're coming back.

As you can see in the pic the scratches are wearing through the outer layer of paint to expose the wood. I'm thinking about maybe just getting some 20 gauge sheet metal or something and bending it around the door so it covers like a foot of the door and goes up from the floor to the handle. But the trim isn't flat and square like the door so I'm not sure what I could do there or if there are already products that I could just buy to fix this problem.

[image: dog scratched through paint on doorway]

Comment: Dog's size/weight? I assume there is a difference between a small 2kg force against a big 60kg... Also for home improving questions there is diy.SE. Here we would answer the "I have tried everything, how to help my anxiuos dog?" question, or "how to train the dog to not paw the door?"

Comment: he is a 42 lb beagle/ basset. also this doesn't belong in the diy home improvement it belongs here in pets. i;'e tried everything to get him to stop but since nothing works i just need to make my door stronger.

Comment: It's on the awkward line between the two groups. Pets is the place where I can think we'll be more likely to find people who have actually dealt with this problem...